# Sending bytes with stx, etx and crc

Tags: encoding, decoding, crc

I'm trying to send chunks of bytes. Each message looks like this: stx + opcode + messageBytes + crc + etx
but the problem is that my etx is 0x03 and sometimes my crc contains byte 3. Then the program reads the message until it comes to the byte 3 in crc and stops. How can i resolve this issue because any byte i pick for etx can be present in crc or message itself.

I tried to send message from client to server using stx crc and etx and expected whole message to come to the server.

Comment: You should be escaping STX, ETX, and ESC wherever they occur when sending the payload between the real STX and ETX, including the opcode, the message, and the CRC, and de-escaping on receipt.

Comment: But what are you sending/receiving with ???

Comment: I guess my solution is to send message length along with etx and stx!

Comment: That's one solution but the design intention of the STX/ETX protocol is that you use escaping. If you have the message length you don't really need STX/ETX at all.